How can i refresh the token automatically in a long running karate tests?
I have a karate-config.js that is used to call the token feature to get the tokens, it returns a map of different tokens with users having different access permissions.
Lets say if i am admin there is different token and if i am normal user than different. In the karate-config.js I use
var jwt =karate.callSingle("classpath:GeTokens.feature",config);
config.admin=jwt.admin;
config.user=jwt.user;

Now this token is used in my feature files directly after it is set up in config.
But the issue is this token expires in 30 minute and we have very large number of tests close to 200 feature files so executing them at once results in token expiry.
Is there any way that i can implement automatic refresh of the token every 25 minutes ?
I have gone through this one How to share variables between feature runs in Karate? also but it is not automatically doing the refresh and not helpful for me as some scenarios also take more than 30 minutes in my case.

if that linked post is not helpful I doubt if you will get any better solutions. lets see if someone else posts an answer

Yeah kind of stuck here only because of this i am not able to run all the tests in one go.

one suggestion is try and get the help of someone who knows java. that link is the right solution

Yes that link is the right solution but it is also getting called only right from somewhere i wanted if there is any way to automate it somehow i am trying that solution also if anyway i can fit that in my scenario.

I've faced this same issue when running longetivy performance tests using the karate-gatling integration. I was pretty easily able to solve the problem using karate's built in callSingleCache. This will initially write your token to a cache file and will re-invoke your callSingle on a given time threshold and re-write the new token back to the cache file for use as normal.
All you need to do is use karate.configure to set the callSingleCache. I set it directly above the callSingle in my karate-config.js
karate.configure('callSingleCache', { minutes: 25 });
var jwt = karate.callSingle('classpath:GeTokens.feature',config);

By default Karate will use target (or build) as the “cache” folder, which you can over-ride by adding a dir key:
karate.configure('callSingleCache', { minutes: 25, dir: 'some/other/folder' });

